# When does Naive Bayes perform better than SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, naive-bayes

In a small text classification problem I was looking at, Naive Bayes has been exhibiting a performance similar to or greater than an SVM and I was very confused.

I was wondering what factors decide the triumph of one algorithm over the other. Are there situations where there is no point in using Naive Bayes over SVMs? Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: Follow this link for a nice and [relevant tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/gaussian-process/rvbm)

Answer (score 28):

**There is no single answer about which is the best classification method for a given dataset**. Different kinds of classifiers should be always considered for a comparative study over a given dataset. Given the properties of the dataset, you might have some clues that may give preference to some methods. However, it would still be advisable to experiment with all, if possible.

Naive Bayes Classifier (NBC) and Support Vector Machine (SVM) have different options including the choice of kernel function for each. **They are both sensitive to parameter optimization (i.e. different parameter selection can significantly change their output)** . So, if you have a result showing that NBC is performing better than SVM. This is only true for the selected parameters. However, for another parameter selection, you might find SVM is performing better.

In general, if the assumption of independence in NBC is satisfied by the variables of your dataset and the degree of class overlapping is small (i.e. potential linear decision boundary), NBC would be expected to achieve good. For some datasets, with optimization using wrapper feature selection, for example, NBC may defeat other classifiers. Even if it achieves a comparable performance, NBC will be more desirable because of its high speed.

In summary, we should not prefer any classification method if it outperforms others in one context since it might fail severely in another one. (**THIS IS NORMAL IN DATA MINING PROBLEMS**).

Comment: (+1) Also called [no free lunch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization). I do not completely agree with the parameter sensitiveness comparison though (Single Decision Tree is one of the most sensitive approaches IMHO), but we should not discuss about that here :).

Comment: @steffen, thanks for your valuable comment. There are many different ways to optimize the models and I agree we cannot generalize which model is more senesitive in all cases. For feature selection, DT are, probably, less sensitive than NBC but it might not be the case in general. I will edit the answer to consider your comment and if you want, you can, also, edit it. Thanks so much :).

Comment: +1 for the comment on parameter sensitivity.  It is also worth noting that much of the theory underpinning SVMs applies to models with a fixed kernel, so as soon as you try to optimise the hyper-parameters (which *must* be done and done carefully) much of the theoretical basis no longer applies.